# List of wxWidgets widgets with images?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm trying to find some widgets for my wxPython program. I'm not looking for anything specific, but I'd like to just browse a Big List with all widgets.

Something like:

```
wx.ComboBox          <image of ComboBox>
wx.Gauge             <image of Gauge>
wx.StaticText        <image of StaticText>
etc.
```

Does anyone know of such a website?

The wxWidgets docs class list (http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/page_class_cat.html) has the images I'm looking for, but they're all on different pages and a pain to look through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend downloading the wxPython demo package. It not only shows almost all the widgets, but it also demonstrates how they work with code examples. You will find the demo on the wxPython's Download page:

- http://wxpython.org/download.php

Once you have that, you can browse the widgets by category or use the handy search control to find the widget(s) you are looking for.

Comment: That'll do! I still would like just a single page, but this works. And for some things, is much better because of the code examples.

Comment: I don't think anyone has compiled a single page of screenshots. The closest you're going to get is the Phoenix documentation which sometimes has screenshots and sometimes doesn't